# Flutter willpopscope

Tags: flutter

I have four screen in the same level with bottom navigation.
I want to handle back pressed in them and I used will pop scope widget , but I have a problem that is on every page when I click back button, just one of the willpop scope run. How does it work ?

Comment: Hey, can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you navigate to a screen (1 of 4 in your case), other screen is disposed, which dispose screen's `WillPopScope` too. When `WillPopScope`'s dispose is called, it's `onWillPop` will not called any more.

Below is a screenshot of `WillPopScope`'s implementation code:

[image: WillPopSope's implementation code screenshot]

When dispose is called, `onWillPop` callback is removed, which is the reason only one `onWillPop`(the current screen) was called in your case.

Comment: What's the solution?